# RSpec how to use a_collection_containing_exactly matcher with an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'd really like to use the a_collection_containing_exactly matcher but with an array in parameters instead of writing values directly, like this

contract_ids_subset = order_summaries_subset.map {|c| c.contract_id.to_i}.compact

allow(Shipping::Owner::Api::Helper).to receive(:order_summaries_by_contract_ids_and_delivery_date).with(
**a_collection_containing_exactly(contract_ids_subset)**, 
delivery_date) {
          order_summaries_subset
        }

**( assume that contract_ids_subset = [11111, 22222, 99999] )**

This work if I hardcode 
a_collection_containing_exactly(11111, 22222, 99999)

But I cant figure out how to use an array [11111, 22222, 99999] with the same results ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [splat](https://jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html) operator in ruby to deconstruct the array. It'll basically take the single argument of the array and deconstruct it such that each value becomes an argument.

So you'd do something like:

```
a_collection_containing_exactly(*contact_ids_subset)
```

Comment: Yay ! Thx Daniel